# Is 'file path' required in hook_menu()?

Tags: 7, routes

I just started learning Drupal 7 Module development. In a tutorial I watched, the person said that

> "In hook_menu(), if we have a **'file'** attribute then the **'file
>   path'** is a must and drupal wont work if it is not declared in drupal 7."

But when I read a book, it said that

> The **'file_path'** is not required in drupal 7 provided that the file
>   is present in the same directory.

As you can see, its a bit confusing. So my questions are

**1) Is 'file path' required in Drupal 7 ?**

**2) When to use 'file path' ?**

I've posted a snippet of the hook_menu implementation :

```
function modulename_menu() {
  $items['...'] = array(
    ....
    ....
    'file' => 'modulename.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module','modulename'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**Note :** Assume that the file is present in the same modules folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence you quoted is wrong. "file path" is not a must, if you set "file"; in fact, by default Drupal will take its value is the directory containing the module implementing the menu. If you want to use a different directory, such as `drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes')`, then you can set "file path."

[_menu_router_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_router_build/7) contains the following code.

```
// Calculate out the file to be included for each callback, if any.
if ($item['file']) {
  $file_path = $item['file path'] ? $item['file path'] : drupal_get_path('module', $item['module']);
  $item['include file'] = $file_path . '/' . $item['file'];
}
```

`$item['module']` is set by [menu_router_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) using the following code.

```
  foreach (module_implements('menu') as $module) {
    $router_items = call_user_func($module . '_menu');
    if (isset($router_items) && is_array($router_items)) {
      foreach (array_keys($router_items) as $path) {
        $router_items[$path]['module'] = $module;
      }
      $callbacks = array_merge($callbacks, $router_items);
    }
  }
```

A module could implement `hook_menu_alter()` to alter `$item['module']`.

Comment: Note for future self: clear caches in-between altering file path.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is 'file path' required in Drupal 7 ?

Required if file being included is not in module path. Its not mandatory if the file is included in the module itself.
[file path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7): The path to the directory containing the file specified in "file". This defaults to the path to the module implementing the hook.

> 2) When to use 'file path' ?

When you want to include a file outside your module.